# Efficient way to check dtype of each row in a series

Tags: python, pandas, series

Say I have mixed ts/other data:

```
ser = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2017/01/05', '2018/01/05'))
ser.loc[3] = 4
type(ser.loc[0])
> pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

I would like to filter for all timestamps. For instance, this gives me what I want:

```
ser.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp))

0       True
1       True
2       True
3      False
4       True
...
```

But I assume it would be faster to use a vectorized solution and avoid `apply`. I thought I should be able to use `where`:

```
ser.where(isinstance(ser, pd.Timestamp))
```

But I get

> ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self

Is there a way to do this? Also, am I correct in my assumption that it would be faster/more 'Pandasic'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends of length of data, but here for small data (365 rows) is faster list comprehension:

```
In [108]: %timeit (ser.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp)))
434 µs ± 57.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [109]: %timeit ([isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) for x in ser])
140 µs ± 5.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [110]: %timeit (pd.to_datetime(ser, errors='coerce').notna())
1.01 ms ± 25.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

But if test larger DataFrame is faster [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with test non missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
ser = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1980/01/05', '2020/01/05'))
ser.loc[3] = 4

print (len(ser))
14611

In [116]: %timeit (ser.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp)))
6.42 ms ± 541 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [117]: %timeit ([isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) for x in ser])
4.9 ms ± 256 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [118]: %timeit (pd.to_datetime(ser, errors='coerce').notna())
4.22 ms ± 167 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Interesting, good to know - sometimes non-Pandas solution is the best

Comment: @JoshFriedlander - Ya, it is for dicsussion, testing in large data, give me a sec.

Answer (score 1):

To address your question of filtering, you can convert to `datetime` and drop NaNs.

```
ser[pd.to_datetime(ser, errors='coerce').notna()]
```

Or, if you don't mind the result being datetime,

```
pd.to_datetime(ser, errors='coerce').dropna()
```

Comment: I need to return a vector of the same size, so can't use the second, but the first works. Thanks! Any idea what's happening with `where`?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander `isinstance` returns a scalar (not vectorised), while you should've passed a series of the same size as `ser` to work.